# Passing stored selector to function - efficiency

Tags: jquery-selectors

I'm storing selectors in two variables. If I create them globally and use in function, duration of operation is about 0.2s

```
window.$my = {
    nameEdit : $('#nameEdit'),
    nameError : $('#nameError')
};

function Validation() {
    console.profile();
    var result = true;
    if ($my.nameEdit.val() == '') {
        $my.nameEdit.addClass('error');
        $my.nameError.css({ 'display': 'block' });      
    }
    else {
        $my.nameEdit.removeClass('error');
        $my.nameError.css({'display':'none'});
    }
    console.profileEnd();
}
```

If I'm binding another function in Validaton() and try to use them i this function, it takes too long (about 0.6s):

```
window.$my = {
    nameEdit : $('#nameEdit'),
    nameError : $('#nameError')
};

function Validation() {
    $my.nameEdit.blur(function (evt) { ValidateName(evt); });
}

function ValidateName(evt) {
    console.profile();
    if ($my.nameEdit.val() == '') {
        $my.nameEdit.addClass('error');
        $my.nameError.css({ 'display': 'block' });      
    }
    else {
        $my.nameEdit.removeClass('error');
        $my.nameError.css({'display':'none'});
    }
    console.profileEnd();
}
```

Comment: `$my.nameEdit.blur(function (evt) { ValidateName(evt); });` why are you using an event handler inside the function